# Can I use infernal machine in all difficulties?

Tags: diablo-iii

I'm new to the game. I got all the requirements to craft an infernal machine playing the Master difficulty. I want to know if it is possible to use it while at hard difficulty. In fact, I am afraid of not being able to defeat the bosses.

So, can I use the infernal machine in all difficulties, or it depends where I get the parts?

Also, is the drop rate any better in a difficulty rather than in another?

Comment: I don't think the organs have a chance to drop at all below t1.  I'm not sure if you can even open them below t1.

Comment: I've read somewhere they can drop at all difficulties now. Really low chance on normal and the like, but I can't remember where.

Comment: @Arperum nope, source: http://www.diablofans.com/forums/diablo-iii-general-forums/diablo-iii-general-discussion/82430-ros-faq-reaper-of-souls-frequently-asked#cachelegs

Comment: @z that tells us that they *can* drop at all levels, but not that the drop chance is the same. EDIT: And it appears to be about Horadric Caches rather than infernal-machine-portal-boss-drops? Or did I read the wrong bit?

Comment: Look at question 8) (scroll up a bit from the point where @z's link drops you in the page) That part explains it.

Comment: @Flyto The exact droprates from T1 to T6 are 25%, 28%, 33%, 38%, 43%, 50% (no drops on difficulties lower than Torment).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**You got all the requirements to craft an infernal machine, I suppose you are talking about the lvl 60 one**

In fact, we are still able to craft the "old" infernal machine. As long as you are lvl 60 and under, the key wardens will drop the keys for the old, pre-patch-2.0 machine. for lvl 61 to 69, there is no way you can have any drops for hellfire rings events. When you reach lvl 70 you will have the key wardens drop the new parts for the new event released in patch 2.0.

I was needed to clarify this before answering your original question. So now..

**So, can I use the infernal machine in all difficulties, or it depends where I get the parts?**

In no way you are restricted to craft or use your machine in any difficulty. However, both Keys and Organs now only drop in Torment I or above at the following rates:

1. Torment I: 25%
2. Torment II: 28%
3. Torment III: 33%
4. Torment IV: 38%
5. Torment V: 43%
6. Torment VI: 50%

Here is my [source](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/forum/topic/11913862084) (blue post).

Comment: great clarification